# What is the underlying connection mode when using live connection? (import or direct query mode)

Tags: powerbi

> Live connections
>
> When connecting to SQL Server Analysis Services,
> there's an option to either import data from or connect live to, the
> selected data model. If you use import, you define a query against
> that external SQL Server Analysis Services source, and the data is
> imported as normal. If you use connect live, there's no query defined,
> and the entire external model is shown in the field list.

My understanding was that import/direct query can be used to query a data source like SQL server. Where as live mode is used to connect to an existing power bi dataset, or SSAS, or azure analysis service.

The above quote says `When connecting to SQL Server Analysis Services, there's an option to either import data from or connect live to, the selected data model.` - So does this mean that the live mode allows us to choose between import/direct query to the live model?

Answer (score 1):

> When connecting to SQL Server Analysis Services, there's an option to
> either import data from or connect live to, the selected data model.

This quote means that you do not have to use a live connection with SSAS models.  Instead you can construct a query and import the data.  The dataset would be limited to whatever was in the query.  If you use a live connection, you have access to the entire model.

Comment: So when using SSAS as data source, then Power BI supports import mode (as per your snswer), direct query mode (the new feature where-in you can have local model) and live mode?

Comment: live and direct query is the same thing, so there are just two modes or you can do a composite of the two.  And yes, SSAS can do both modes.

Comment: Direct query to a live ssas can be made, this is the new feature. To make your own model after pulling in the ssas model.

Comment: I haven't heard of any changes - working off of this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-dataset-modes-understand  -- I'm not sure I understand what the change would actually be

Comment: Here is what I meant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-datasets-azure-analysis-services#using-directquery-for-live-connections

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It seems they are saying in order to use this preview feature, you need to have a local copy of the model.  So if you're in a live connection, you'll be prompted to switch to a DirectQuery connection.  The difference between Live and DirectQuery is not abundantly clear, maybe it's just in the ability to modify the model.

Comment: Ok so with that understanding (that for SSAS we can either have a live connection or direct query), now going back to my question it says `When connecting to SQL Server Analysis Services, there's an option to either import data from or connect live to, the selected data model.` - so what does import mean? Can we import the data from SSAS into PBI dataset? I haven't come across any official documentation that says this - can you point me to some msdn reference?

Comment: This is a good article explaining the differences, I think the FAQ is especially helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-analysis-services-tabular-data